# If God created evil would that make Him evil or, the creator of evil?

Tags: theology, christianity, problem-of-evil

God cannot be what He has created. So if He creates something there will be a gap between Him and His creation. That gap is defined in various ways. e.g.
God alone can create. God is holy. Evil exists. Therefore God had a holy motive for making something other than Himself. To prove and demonstrate that He is perfect He sent His Son to fulfil the Law and by keeping this privilege for His Son He had a motive to make sure that Adam did not obey. And thus a rationale to predestine Adam to fail. If a cook makes a cake they themselves do not become a cake. God is the only Alpha. God is at the head of every causal chain. When Christians protect God from the accusation of creating evil, because they think that that would make Him evil, they are saying something outside God can create which is to make themselves into gods i.e. first causes. Adam was "very good" i.e. fit for purpose. The purpose being to show man's status as created and therefore having no ability other than that with which he was created . Incapable of obeying God of himself but also capable of doing so when not of himself.

I am a Christian and a hard determinist. I get the impression that some people think that if God created evil that would make Him evil. And they do not explore the idea of a holy motive behind evil. Here "judgement" is living with the consequences of how we were made. The sheep go one way because they are sheep, and not because they had the free will to choose to be sheep. The goats go another way because they are goats, and goats do not become goats by choosing to be goats, it just the way they were made. We give back to God an account of the lives we were given *apodo* = "give back". Does God desire people to obey His Law? "Yes" if He gives us the grace to do so and "no" if He does not. Back to the question: It appears to me that if God had not created anything then evil [disobedience to the Law] would not exist. God by deciding to create is responsible for everything that occurs as a result of His creating [including evil], but as God is holy creating evil only means what it says. There is no logically inevitable link that means that creating disobedience cannot be a holy act.

Comment: For reference.. this is called the 'Epicurean argument' against the existance of an omnibenevolent God. Epicurus follows on to say that if God exists but does not prevent misery then he is our enemy and rather than worship.. should simply be counted amongst life's other travails. Great man... Problem solved.

Comment: If you create a new paint color, does that turn into that paint color?

Comment: The Creator of evil = the creator of evil.                                                                    _Also, it's ill advised to apply our notion of evil to an entity that we, ourselves have described as beyond our comprehension._

Answer (score 3):

Most if not all Christians would reject the antecedent you presented and instead simply say God gave us free will and we are free to choose to do things that he approves of (good) or disapproves of (evil).

In this sense good and evil are not notions that are created, but rather consequences of free will.

Comment: In your view are some notions created and some not created or are they all uncreated?